# Javascript: how to append data to a file

Tags: javascript, activex

how can i append data to a file using javascript?

i tried to use this code, but i got an error:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemOject");
var filepath = fso.GetFile("member.txt");
var fileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 8);
file.WriteLine(id + "|" + pass);
fileObject.close();
```

the error is on `var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemOject");`, written: `Error: Automation server can't create object`

is there any other way to append the file using javascript or the way to fix this? thanks :)

**EDIT:**
i have doing what's written on [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex?SignedIn=1), and it still not working :/

Comment: Make sure you have `scrrun.dll` installed and registered into your OS. A quicktest: write to commandline: `scrrun.dll`. If you'll get a `WINDOWS` error, the dll exists, if error text occurs only in commanline, there is not `scrrun.dll` installed/registered. You can also try to find the file from `system32`-folder

Comment: i've run it and it gives me a warning that i wanted to open the file :/

Comment: Well, the installation seems to be OK then... And you've switched all the necessary settings to "insecure" mode?

Comment: how can i switch it to insecure mode?

Comment: You wrote this: "i have doing what's written on this". That's "insecure" mode. Are you getting the error from `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemOject")`-line or `var filepath = fso.GetFile("member.txt");`

Comment: oh, if that's insecure mode, yes i have. :)

Comment: I just realized after wasting an hour, the OP misspelled "Scripting.FileSystemOject", there's 'b' missing in object. That's why it's giving out that error (even if you apply the fix.) Don't copy it into your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized these in your code:

```
var fileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 8,true);
```

You'll need the `true`-argument, if the file does not exist, or you want to overwrite/append it.

```
var filepath = fso.GetFile("member.txt");// This won't work.
var filepath = "your_filePath"; // Use this instead
var fileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 8, true);
```

`OpenTextFile()` needs a path as a string like `"D:/test/file.txt"`. `GetFile()` returns an object, which you can *see* as a string (`D:\test\file.txt`), but it's not a string. Use also absolute paths, relative paths don't seem to work by my experience.

**EDIT**

Add the code below to the `<head>`-part of your html-file, then save locally as a hta (with file extension `hta`, not `htm` or `html`).

```
<hta:application
  applicationName="MyApp"
  id="myapp"
  singleInstance="yes"
/>
```

Then run the hta-file. If you still getting an ActiveX-error, it's not supported by your OS. If this works, you haven't done all the security settings correct.

**EDIT II**

In this case it's not very usefull to get the path through ActiveX, you'll need to write it literal anyway. And I'm not supposed to do your homeworks, but this does the trick...

```
var filepath = new String(fso.GetFile("member.txt")).replace(/\\/g,'/');
```

And don't forget what I've said above about using absolute paths...

Comment: i'm doing the same thing but it still shows an error. it seems that the error is still coming from the `var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemOject");` though

Comment: @aquatorrent Can't you see it with F12-tools? Are you running this locally or from server?

Comment: oh, i forgot that i put a try catch there :P i removed it and got the error, still the same though : `SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object`

Comment: just realized that i mistyped `ActiveXObject` to `ActiveXOject` XD and it works! anyway, do you know how can i get the filepath? it seems that it would be easier if i can get the filepath using a code instead of copying it myself :P

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because there are security restrictions which donot allow the activex to run. change your security settings to allow the activex if your using internet explorer (which i think you are).
This might be useful http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex
Cheers

EDIT: i have doing what's written on this, and it still not working :/ 
 * try Restarting your browser

Comment: yes i have, i close and open it again but it still not working. i have done it several times though . .

Answer (score 0):

The `8` in the `OpenTextFile` function specify that you want to append to the file. Your problem comes from the security restriction of your browser. To make it work you'll have to lower the security level, which is not really recommended.

Comment: yeah, i actually want to append a string to the file. am i wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in this comment

[Javascript: how to append data to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193532/javascript-how-to-append-data-to-a-file/10193685#comment35969315_10193532)

the cause of the error `Error: Automation server can't create object` is the typo in the progid passed to `ActiveXObject`: Oject instead of O**b**ject:

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemOject");

there is a missing `b`!